# Should registration be required for an application which relies on success based on unique barcode?

Tags: mobile, application-design

The application goes something like this:

- Users download app and upon downloading, a unique barcode will be presented to them.
- The barcode (via phone) is scanned at the checkout (so it eliminates paper receipts).
- The receipt will then be send to there phone because of there unique barcode.

I am wondering two things:

1. Will I require users to register for this application AND only then, present their barcode to them? I am wondering this because how will the store, i.e. how will the supermarket know that this barcode belongs to Alice's phone? Which also brings me onto question two...
2. How will supermarket scanners know this barcode is not a product? From my understanding, items in a supermarket are scanned, and stored on a database, so how will my external barcode be recognized?

Is this an effective way to go about this? I am still in the "idea" phase, so I am open to alternative approaches.

Comment: They will know it's not a product because it's not in their system (unless you accidentally create barcodes that relate to a product which you should not do). So somebody has to enter your barcode in the system for it to be recognized. Also they would have to change their software to handle sending the receipt (what they won't do unless you offer a service that makes money for them). Also there are most likely better options to implement such functionality (maybe on the line of Apple's iBeacon or whatever).

Comment: What problem does this application solve?

Comment: @DanPichelman 30 cm of paper trash most people throw away anyway. But I guess you could track your purchases and later get some statistics on where you wasted the most money.

Comment: @thorstenmüller - Yes, I plan to monitor shopping habits via these "e-receipts" which will eventually allow me to advertise products for these supermarkets. Initially, I was thinking that users must register their details on the app, which would allow them to see their barcode. All registered details for the app would then be stored on a central database, and access to this database will be given to supermarkets. This way scanner barcodes will be checked in this central database and then loaded onto the device. Maybe I am overthinking this

Comment: @DanPichelman - It eliminates the need for paper receipts which is a plus on the environmental side, but it can also be used to monitor user shopping habits more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is registration required?

When the app is launched, it connects to the server and tells it an unique identifier. The server generates a barcode and binds it to that identifier. The network connection stays open while the app is running.

When the server receives a receipt with a barcode from a point-of-sale, it can look up the identifier for that barcode, look up the active network connection for that identifier, and push the receipt data.

No registration required. Neither for the consumer nor for the point-of-sale.

When you plan to monetize your app by logging all purchases of each user, data-mine it to generate a comprehensive consumer profile and then sell that profile to market research, then the identifier sent from the app to the server should be a constant identifier of the device, like its IMEI number.

When you plan to respect your users privacy and find a more ethical method of monetization, then the identifier should be randomly-generated each time the app is launched and be long enough to make collisions impossible (like a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)).

### How does the barcode scanner tell your codes apart from product codes?

This is a tricky one, because you will have to dive into the technical details of point-of-sale barcode scanners and see what their soft- and hardware can and can't do (this is not my area of expertise, but I could imagine that there are scanners which decode the barcodes completely in hardware). And there are quite a lot of different POS systems on the market. Dealing with all the different POS systems will be the hardest part of your project anyway.

- Maybe you can get the scanners to read a new barcode format which is completely different than [the EAN format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29) usually used for retail products.
- Maybe you could register your own EAN company number so you get a range of EAN codes for exclusive use by your application
- Maybe you can use EAN encoding but with values which are invalid. Your codes could for example turn the check-digit into its binary compliment. That way the POS terminal could check if the check-digit is correct according to EAN or correct according to yours and process the code accordingly.
- Maybe you can use arbitrary EAN codes which might also be used by actual products, but have the POS terminal handle them differently depending on its current state.

Comment: Also keep in mind that using hardware-based ids like IMEI for advertising purposes is forbidden; both android and ios provide advertising identifiers and guidelines around their use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your knowledge has cleared up some of my thoughts, but I have one question. You said, and I quote "push the receipt data", how does this work? So, on launch, an app, let's say an android app, connects to a server, which gives the app a `unique identifier`. The server then generates one single barcode for the identifier (Which allows the app as a whole to be uniquely identified from millions others). The barcode on the app for each user will be the same as the barcode generated by the server? I.e. will Alice and Fred see the same barcode on there Smartphones? Part 1/2

Comment: And how does push the receipt data work? Is it essentially similar to email? Apologies if I have misunderstood you, just trying to gain a better understanding :) Part 2/2.

Comment: @Freddy No two users which use the app *at the same time* should get the same barcode, because then you can't send the receipt to the right person, but depending on how large your number-space is you might have to reuse codes used before.

Comment: @Freddy Regarding pushing the receipt data: This would be a simple network message over the open network connection. Before you undertake this project you might want to familiarize yourself with the basics of network socket programming.

Comment: I am starting to understand your approach now. Just a final comment, do you think my approach is the best way to go about this? I am looking for a cost effective method to approach this as my app will be free (with revenue generated off marketing). I already have a very limited target group and want to find the most cost effective solution.

Comment: Does this approach rely on internet access? So if someone does not have access to W-Fi or mobile data, will access to the server be available?

Comment: @Freddy This solution will always depend on internet connectivity because you somehow need to get data from POS to cellphone.

Comment: Understood. Once the barcode is scanned from the device, how will the receipt data be sent to the phone? I know you have covered this but I mean, so the barcode is scanned, Alice has brought milk and bread, when the barcode is scanned the store sends the data to the server from where the unique identifier is located? I understand the servers role is to identify which device belongs to whom, but is the store responsible to process information of what has been brought?

Comment: @Freddy the store sends it to the server and the server sends it to the device.

Comment: Ok, just a summary, at the end of my shopping, I present my barcode. The barcode is scanned and data regarding all my purchased goods and it's cost is sent to the server. The server then communicates the receipt to my device?

Comment: @Freddy Now you got it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Phillipp, you have shown me an alternative way to achieve my goal, will research this more :) thanks again!